# RailsでのValidation処理の設計について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsで画像をS3にアップロードする機能を作成したいと考えています。
しかしここでValidation周りの設計に悩んでおります。

まずサイトの機能としては、入力フォーム画像のURLを指定しSubmitすると、それがS3にアップロードされます
またアップロードした写真を管理できるよう、データベースに画像に紐付いたレコードであるPicutreレコードを保存したいです。
またPictureテーブルは将来的にはタグなどを管理させたいですが、現状はカラムはありません。

プログラムの流れを説明させていただくと、
・入力フォームに写真のURLを指定し、Submitします。
・サーバ側で、まずその入力がURLの表記として正しいかチェックします。
・そのURLからファイルをTmpFileにダウンロードします。
・Pictureレコードを作成し、保存します。
・画像をS3にアップロードします。この時のファイル名はPictureのカラムのIDにしたいと考えています。
・最後にResponseを返します。

ここでValidation周りをどのように設計すれば良いのかわからず困っています。

まず入力された画像URLのチェックです。
このURLは、Pictureテーブルには存在しないカラムです。なので、モデルにvalidatesをかけないように思えます。
私としては調べたところ、FormObjectというのがあり、これを使うことで仮想的にmodelを作れ、Validationをかけるようでした。なので、ImageUploadFormのようなクラスをコントローラ内に作り、ここで入力されたURLがURLとして正しい形式かチェックするのが良いように思えました。
この設計は正しいでしょうか？

次にURL先からデータをダウンロードする部分です。
ここもユーザが入力するものなので、架空のアドレスなどが指定される場合もあると思います。
ではこれも先ほどのImageUploadFormのValidationの処理の一環なのでしょうか？
ただ、実際にファイルをダウンロードするので、戻り値はTmpFileのように思えます。これはvalidatesでどのようにかけば良いでしょうか？

最後にValidationとは関係ないですが、
S3にアップロードするための画像のファイル名を、レコードのIDにしたいため、先にレコードの保存処理していることです。
これだともしS3へのアップロードがなんらかの理由で失敗した場合、レコードを明示的に削除する必要性があります。
もし何か他に良い方法があれば、知りたいです。

抽象的な質問で申し訳ないです。何かお気付きの点などありましたら、ご回答いただけると助かります。

Comment: 「またアップロードした写真を管理できるよう、データベースに画像に紐付いたレコードであるPicutreレコードを保存したいです。」ということはPicturesテーブルにURLを持つカラムがあるのが自然な気がしたのですが、S3に保存したURLはどこに持つのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。S3に保存した場合、ファイル名はIDです。またバケット名は決め打ちをする予定なので、その2つから特定できるように設計しておりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> このURLは、Pictureテーブルには存在しないカラムです。なので、モデルにvalidatesをかけないように思えます。

いえ。書けます。

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  attr :url

  validates_presence_of :url
end
```

こんな感じで、DBのカラムに対応しない属性をモデルに持たせ、バリデーションを定義することもできます。

素直に実装するのであれば、上記のようにPictureにurl属性を定義し、適当なコールバックで画像のダウンロードやアップロードを実装する形になります。

ところで、CarrierWaveという定番のアップローダのライブラリがありますので、それを使う方が簡単で確実かと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。このようにすればValidationをかけたのですね、勉強になりました。この形で実装していこうと思います。コールバックの件、確かにその通りですね。データを作る＝画像をアップロードなので。その設計で行かせていただきます。CarrierWaveは知っていたのですが、勉強という目的もあり今回は採用しておりませんでした。しかしご紹介ありがとうございます。